# How to copy directories in OS X 10.7.3?

Tags: macos, directory, copy, home-directory

Hi I'm trying to copy my rails_projects directory from haseebjaved/Desktop/rails_projects to my home directory, which is haseebjaved.

How can I do this via the Command Line?

Also, can I see my home directory on the UI or only via the Command Line in Mac OS X?

Is it possible to copy directories to and from my home directory via the UI? Or only via Command Line?

Thank you

Answer (score 340, accepted):

Is there something special with that directory or are you really just asking how to copy directories?

Copy recursively via CLI:

```
cp -R <sourcedir> <destdir>
```

If you're only seeing the files under the `sourcedir` being copied (instead of `sourcedir` as well), that's happening because you kept the trailing slash for `sourcedir`:

```
cp -R <sourcedir>/ <destdir>
```

The above only copies the files and their directories inside of `sourcedir`. Typically, you want to include the directory you're copying, so drop the trailing slash:

```
cp -R <sourcedir> <destdir>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I'm trying to copy three sub-directories within rails_projects to my home directory haseebjaved. When I issue the following command: cp -r ~/Desktop/rails_projects haseebjaved , the command effectively copies the three subdirectories from rails_projects to haseebjaved and makes a new folder named haseebjaved in my home directory haseebjaved. What I want is the directory rails_projects to show up under my home directory haseebjaved just like other folders such as Downloads, Desktop, etc.

Comment: I'm using the search function with Finder now and it's much better but I don't see my home directory there in Favorites or anywhere else. Very new to Mac OS X and Rails.

Comment: `cp -r ~/Desktop/rails_projects ~` is what you want

Comment: At least you should have Macintosh HD in your favorites. Start there and navigate to /Users. There should be your homedir inside. Drag&Drop it to your favorites.

Comment: Thanks Peter. There was no Mac HD in favorites but I found the home dir and made it a favorite. Any other such tips for a newbie?

Comment: Well... you know already how to copy directories and how to see them. Is there any more one could do with a Mac? ;-) Seriously, glad that I could help you.

Comment: Here is the manual from `cp`: ```-R    If source_file designates a directory, cp copies the directory and the entire subtree connected at that point.  **If the source_file ends in a /, the
           contents of the directory are copied rather than the directory itself.**  This option also causes symbolic links to be copied, rather than indirected
           through, and for cp to create special files rather than copying them as normal files.  Created directories have the same mode as the corresponding
           source directory, unmodified by the process' umask.```

Comment: Just two cents about copy folders from command line: ditto command http://ss64.com/osx/ditto.html

PS. Unlike cp -R, if the destination folder already exists, the existing contents will be merged with the contents of the folder being copied.

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr

```
cp -R "/src/project 1/App" "/src/project 2"
```

Explanation:

Using quotes will cater for spaces in the directory names

```
cp -R "/src/project 1/App" "/src/project 2"
```

If the App directory is specified in the destination directory:

```
cp -R "/src/project 1/App" "/src/project 2/App"
```

and "/src/project 2/App" already exists the result will be "/src/project 2/App/App"

Best not to specify the directory copied in the destination so that the command can be repeated over and over with the expected result.

Inside a bash script:

```
cp -R "${1}/App" "${2}"
```